# How to change a pythons code using scipy.weave? (how a code to do quicker?)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, scipy

In Python:
I have 2 arrays: lon, lat (more than 500 000 points).

```
     lon = numpy.array()
     lat = numpy.array()

     flag = True
     while flag:
        lon1 = lon[:-1]
        lon2 = lon[1:]
        lat1 = lat[:-1]
        lat2 = lat[1:]

        '''distance'''
        x = (lon2 - lon1)
        y = (lat2 - lat1)
        d = numpy.sqrt(x * x + y * y)

        min = numpy.min(d)
        if min < 0.015:
            j = numpy.where(d == min)[0][0]

            lon[j] = (lon[j] + lon[j + 1]) / 2
            lat[j] = (lat[j] + lat[j + 1]) / 2

            lon = numpy.delete(lon, j + 1)
            lat = numpy.delete(lat, j + 1)

        else:
            flag = False
```

This code works very slowly!

1. Prompt please, **how a code to do quicker?**
2. I know there is **scipy.weave**. Prompt please, how to change a code using **scipy.weave**?

   ```
   import scipy
   from scipy import weave

   codeC = """
   ???
   """
   scipy.weave.inline(codeC, ['lon', 'lat'], compiler='gcc')
   ```

Thanks.

**Update:**

```
    lon1 = lon[:-1]
    lon2 = lon[1:]
    lat1 = lat[:-1]
    lat2 = lat[1:]

    x = (lon2 - lon1)
    y = (lat2 - lat1)
    d = x * x + y * y

    while True and d.size > 1:

        j = np.argmin(d)
        if d[j] > min_radius:
            break

        lon[j] = (lon[j] + lon[j + 1]) / 2
        lat[j] = (lat[j] + lat[j + 1]) / 2

        '''lon = np.delete(lon, j + 1)
           lat = np.delete(lat, j + 1)
           d = np.delete(d, j)'''
        if j == (d.size - 1):
            lon = lon[:j + 1]
            lat = lat[:j + 1]
            d = d[:j]
        else:
            lon = np.hstack((lon[:j + 1], lon[j + 2:]))
            lat = np.hstack((lat[:j + 1], lat[j + 2:]))
            d = np.hstack((d[:j], d[j + 1:]))


        if j > 0:
            x = lon[j] - lon[j - 1]
            y = lat[j] - lat[j - 1]
            d[j - 1] = x * x + y * y
        if j < (d.size - 1):
            x = lon[j + 1] - lon[j]
            y = lat[j + 1] - lat[j]
            d[j] = x * x + y * y
```

@ilmiacs, @Jaime, @Luke, thanks!
It works much quicker!

**But** as a whole the code works very long at an array of 500 points...:(((

Comment: Yes, because it still is `O(N**2)`. The code will remain slow on big datasets as long as this is the case, no matter whether you implement it in python or C. At least, the distances are not recalculated anymore at each step. See my last edit on what would be required to make the algorithm run in `O(N log N)`. It definitely is possible, but it is not trivial.

Comment: @ilmiacs thanks for the help, Yes it is interesting to me if to you not difficult I like to see your thoughts on an optimal data structure...

Comment: @Olga I think ilmiacs has shaved as much as can be shaved to implement your algorithm with numpy. You can now try to implement doubly linked lists, and some sort of priority queue for the distances, which is going to be a big mess, or you can ask yourself: do I really need to be using this specific algorithm? If you changed your algorithm around a little you could get ridiculous improvements in performance, obtaining results very similar (although not identical) to what you are getting now. Let us know if that is an option, maybe by asking a new question, and SE will help you out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are redoing the whole expensive calculation on each iteration in your loop. One iteration only removes one node and then when removing one element you copy the whole arrays and redo the distance calculation. then you search the next node.

Thus, your code is suboptimal as it runs at least `O(N^2)`. However, for what you want to achieve,  `O(N log N)` or possibly `O(N)` would be sufficient.

A simple python module without numpy should be fast enough if you rearrange the algorithm. Recipe:

1. Avoid recalculating the whole distance array. Only two values need to be recalculated when you remove one node.
2. Avoid the copying. It is expensive as well.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

An example implementation without recalculating the distance array would be this:

```
lon = numpy.array()
lat = numpy.array()

lon1 = lon[:-1]
lon2 = lon[1:]
lat1 = lat[:-1]
lat2 = lat[1:]

'''distance'''
x = (lon2 - lon1)
y = (lat2 - lat1)
d = x * x + y * y

while True:
    min = numpy.min(d)
    if min < 0.015 * 0.015:
        j = numpy.where(d == min)[0][0]
    else:
        break

    lon[j] = (lon[j] + lon[j + 1]) / 2
    lat[j] = (lat[j] + lat[j + 1]) / 2

    lon = numpy.delete(lon, j + 1)  # <-- you spend most of the time here
    lat = numpy.delete(lat, j + 1)  # <-- and here

    d = numpy.delete(d, j)      # <-- and here

    x = lon[j]-lon[j-1]
    y = lat[j]-lat[j-1]
    d[j-1] = x * x + y * y
    x = lon[j+1]-lon[j]
    y = lat[j+1]-lat[j]
    d[j] = x * x + y * y
```

Although this will give you a boost, you are still `O(N^2)`, because of the extensive copying. To avoid that, you'd need to store your arrays in a doubly linked list. Then removing an element would be of `O(1)`, not `O(N)`. With the linked list, your worst operation would be the finding of the minimum. This you could improve by introducing a sorted version of `d`, where you also would keep track of the positions in `d`. You would need to keep track of the changes though. But finally you would arrive at an algorithm that is `O(N log N)`.

**EDIT 2:**

Comparing squared distances is not necessary, too, as pointed out by @Jaime. I have corrected the code above.

**EDIT 3:**

Over the weekend I was thinking more about the algorithm, which turns out to be a very interesting problem and fun to think about. I wanted to share my thoughts.

To get it work `O(N log N)` is less trivial than I thought. I have suggested to keep a list `sorted_d` and manage it. Each time a link is removed, we have to update two entries in `sorted_d`. This means, we have to find the new positions of the two corresponding distances in `sorted_d`. In a normal list, finding the position can be done by bisection in `O(log N)`. However, as far as I understand it, bisection is not viable in a linked list and turns `O(N)`.  This is the problem. I would be pleased if anyone could prove me wrong and show up a way to  to insert an element in a sorted linked list in `O(log N)`. I personally don't see it.

There is an alternative to the linked list for `sorted_d`, however. All one needs is a B-tree or a Patricia-tree, that works with floats as keys. Insertion in such a tree can be done in (quite fast) 'O(log N)`. However, I do not know of any standard implementations of such a tree. Standard implementations work on strings or integers. Therefore, we could achieve it if we had an ordered and collision free mapping from floats to ints. Such a mapping does not exist in general, but could be beyond doubt be constructed for any particular dataset. And the dataset in question is beyond doubt particular: There certainly is an upper bound and a precision.

Hope this helps. If there is further interest, I could also present my thoughts on an optimal data structure for this problem.

Comment: I can't change algorithm that there was no repeated calculation of distance((

Comment: Why? Where is the problem?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a modification of the algorithm that does not repeat the distance calculation. Still far from ideal, though.

Comment: +1 for the doubly linked lists idea. And while it is peanuts compared to the array copying, please get rid of all those `np.sqrt` and compare squared distances...

Comment: I also thought about keeping the distances in a heap, including a reference to their position. What I couldn't figure out is how to go about the distances you modify at each step. Would finding where those are, modifying them, and keeping the thing properly ordered, not end up being as messy as ordering the whole thing over and over?

Comment: @Jaime The `d` and the `sorted_d` would be both in linked lists and they would need to have pointers to each other. Once you set it up, which is `O(N log N)`, the removal can be done in `O(log N)` per iteration. It's not `O(1)` because you have to find the position where to insert the new distances in `sorted_d`. The total thing is still `O(N log N)`.

Comment: I think your code will break down when recalculating the distances if the minimum distance is either at the first or last position of the `d` array, you probably want to stick a couple of `if`s in there for completeness.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. You are right. This is left as an exercise to the one who has the problem. :-)

Comment: Using min() and where() together is redundant and surprisingly expensive. Instead use argmin(). This should speed things up a lot.

Comment: @ilmiacs Thanks, I have updated my code, it works quicker, but not at a big array of data..(

Comment: @Jaime Thanks,I have updated my code, it works quicker, but not at a big array of data..(

Comment: @Luke Thanks,I have updated my code, it works quicker, but not at a big array of data..(